# JMeter - Parallel controller transaction with dynamic name fails from second iteration

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter, controller, jmeter-plugins

Plugin used : Parallel Controller & Sampler
Controller used : Parallel Controller

Parallel controller name in script : ParaTrx2_${__Random(1,1000,uniqueID)}
Above controller having 2 requests and name conataining unique id generated at controller level.
We get error on console when try to run script- **"java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to reset the thread name"**

This works fine when we switch to tranaction controller. Also if we remove ${__Random(1,1000,uniqueID)} from controller name then scripts works fine for all iterations.

Is there any way to handle this scenario as we need unique id to be part of transaction name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename the Parallel Controller and eventually its children according to your needs using i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the code like:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()

def postfix = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 1000)

prev.setSampleLabel('ParaTrx2_' + postfix)

prev.getSubResults().each { subResult ->
    subResult.setSampleLabel(postfix as String)
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! I will try once and let you know.